# Creation of postgresql table on docker run

Tags: docker, postgresql

I want to create a Dockerfile that runs a PostgreSQL database when I run that container.

So what I did was making a Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest

COPY *.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The Dockerfile copies the initialization script "postgres.sh" to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/.
The postgres.sh script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

su postgres -c "psql << EOF
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '123';
create database shippingchallenge;
\c shippingchallenge;
create table people(firstname CHAR(20), surname CHAR(30));
insert into people values ('Pieter', 'Pauwels');
EOF"
```

So what I want to do is create a database "shippingchallenge" with a table "people" with 2 values: "firstname " and "surname".
This works fine if I would use `sudo docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash` and I paste this.

But when I use the method described above and I run the image created from this `sudo docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 <image>` I get the following error:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.
 
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF18".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english". 

Data page checksums are disabled. 

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix 
selecting default maxconnections ... 100 
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB 
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC 
creating configuration files ... ok 
running bootstrap script ... ok 
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok 
syncing data to disk ... ok 

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections 
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A or 
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
 
Success. You can now start the database server using: 

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start 
    
waiting for server to start....2020-12-19 12:42:09.749 UTC [45] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1 pgdg100+1) on x86_64 pc linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2020-12-19 12:42:09.754 UTC [45] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-12-19 12:42:09.771 UTC [46] LOG: database system was shut down at 2020-12-19 12:42:07 UTC
2020-12-19 12:42:09.778 UTC [45] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
 done 
server started 

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres.sh 
Password: su: Authentication failure
```

Content of `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so





session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

session    optional   pam_mail.so nopen

session    required   pam_limits.so

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: don't you need to specify the user as well `sudo docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 <image>`?

Comment: I tried this, still the same error. By default the user postgres is used.

Docker Hub postgres documentation:
"POSTGRES_USER
This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of postgres will be used."

Comment: omit the password `sudo docker run -p 5432:5432 <image>` and see if it still fails, sounds you have wrong password, `123` should be password to db user

Comment: So without the ```-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123``` option?
Then I get the following:
`[sudo] password for pieter:
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since no issue was found on `/bin/su` executable permissions and the content of `/etc/pam.d/su` and `/etc/pam.d/su-l`. The `image` should be fine !

After I've pulled the image locally, it seems that the error is due to `su postgres -c`  ; It should be deleted because if you add `whoami` to the script you will notice that the script will be run per default with `postgresql` and that's because the container made an `su` to `postgres` when launching because the daemon needs to be started with this user.

**Docker file** :

```
FROM registry.hub.docker.com/library/postgres
COPY postgres.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres.sh
```

**Script** :

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami 
psql << EOF
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '123';
create database shippingchallenge;
\c shippingchallenge;
create table people(firstname CHAR(20), surname CHAR(30));
insert into people values ('Pieter', 'Pauwels');
EOF
```

**TEST** :

```
docker exec -it <container> bash 
su postgres 
psql
postgres=# \l
```

**OUTPUT** (the table have been created and the owner is postgres) :

```
shippingchallenge|postgres|UTF8|en_US.utf8|en_US.utf8|
```

That's why `su` was asking for the password of `postgres` user and since nothing is passed you got ***Authentication Failure*** during the build.

Comment: Why would the `su` executable have the wrong permissions in the container? How would that `chmod` command remove the need to provide the `postgres` user's password?

Comment: Indeed, this has no effect. Thanks for thinking along. Still looking further for a solution.

Comment: Where did you get the image ? I've tried it with docker.io and it's fine there is no permission issue. Use instead /bin/su, i have updated the answer and check / post the permissions in the question.

Comment: Ok, share the following outputs : docker run -it <image> bash -c `'cat /etc/pam.d/su; cat /etc/pam.d/su-l'` ; `docker run -it <image> bash -c 'grep postg /etc/passwd'` ; From where did you get this image ? which registry ?

Comment: @RedaSalih I got it from Docker Hub.

Comment: Ok, I tried adding chaning the /bin/su permissions, still got the same error. Output from `sudo docker run -it <image> bash -c 'ls -ltr /bin/su'`:

* Without `RUN chmod u+s /bin/su` in Dockerfile:   -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 63568 Jan 10  2019 /bin/su
* With `RUN chmod u+s /bin/su` in Dockerfile -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 63568 Jan 10  2019 /bin/su

Output from `sudo docker run -it <image> bash -c 'grep postg /etc/passwd'`:
      postgres:x:999:999::/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash

Comment: Output from `sudo docker run -it <image> bash -c 'cat /etc/pam.d/su; cat /etc/pam.d/su-l'`:
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session


#%PAM-1.0
auth            include         su
account         include         su
password        include         su
session         optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session         include         su

Comment: Output from `sudo docker run -it <image> bash -c 'cat /etc/pam.d/su; cat /etc/pam.d/su-l'` WITH `RUN chmod u+s /bin/su`:
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session


#%PAM-1.0
auth            include         su
account         include         su
password        include         su
session         optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session         include         su

Comment: I think there is some lines missing in /etc/pam.d/su ; could you edit the question with full content of this file `sudo docker run -it <image>  bash -c 'grep -v "^#" /etc/pam.d/su;'`

Comment: @RedaSalih did it. Thanks alot for your time.

Comment: No Problem, I've maid an edit I think the last one hopefully it works  because i have tested it and it works :)

Comment: Your answer would benefit from having all non-working suggestions removed, and then reworking the rest of the text into a coherent and easy to follow explanation without several "edit" subsections.

Comment: Yes @Kusalananda, i will do it, tought all the steps can be helpful because this issue may come from any of the points i revealed, but once he confirmed the source of the image these points can be ignored.

Comment: @RedaSalih great explenation! 100x "thank you!" for all your help!

Comment: (It worked great  for me by just using `FROM postgres` and I had the execution bit enabled on postgres.sh. But that doesn't matter at all.) Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I see , Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Placement of a script file with SQL statements into the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory does the thing, when one builds *custom* image with the official Postgres *base* image https://github.com/docker-library/postgres

```
docker-context-dir
  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    |-create-table.sql
  |-Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY docker-entrypoint-initdb.d /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

create-table.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...);
```